# I am trying to run PythonScripts and Hatch in the cmd by using the command " cd Downloads/PythonScripts/Hatch"

Tags: python, cmd, cd

I am trying to run PythonScripts and Hatch on my cmd by running the command " cd Downloads/PythonScripts/Hatch" but everytime I try this, the response is " the system cannot find the path specified." May I know how to cd into the folder such that the files appear in the cmd and not in another location.

I have tried to search many websites for an answer but all to no avail. Is this a path issue? can anyone help me with this? Sorry, but I am noob at coding and programming as I just started 2 weeks ago. Thanks for anyone's help! I am using python 2.7.17 and windows 10.

Comment: It's not a Python thing. `cd` *without* a leading backslash (or slash, as you are using – and modern Windows happily accept) looks for the path **in your current directory**. This suggests you are not at a place where "Downloads" is a subdirectory of.

Comment: what is my current directory? or is there any recommended way I can try to fix this? Thank you so much.

Comment: sir, you are a genius. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the current working directory contains a directory named `Downloads`, the path will not be found.

My guess is that you want to use:

```
CD /D "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\PythonScripts\Hatch"
```

Avoid hardcoding `C:\Users\username` since that might not be the correct location. The system knows the correct location and puts it into the `USERPROFILE` environment variable.

If the `Downloads` directory is in a different location, then enter the path to it.

```
CD /D "C:\the\other\place\Downloads\PythonScripts\Hatch"
```

Comment: so what can i type in the cmd because there is a directory called downloads in my c drive

Comment: @dianpiggy - I added to the answer. Does that answer your question?

Comment: You do not need to add USERPROFILE to the PATH.

Comment: my downloads directory is in my file explorer so when i input "cd", does the system register?

Comment: Just to confirm, does cd mean the C drive?

Comment: `cd` neans  "change directory". Use the command `CD /?` to read about it.

Comment: oh sorry, i think i phrased my question wrongly. allow me to edit

Answer (score 0):

Is the downloads folder located in the same folder from which you are running the cmd? (standard would be c:\Users*username*). If not - try using the full path.